# Error cvc-complex-type.2.4.a

Tags: xml

I have the xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<ns3:dadoTransporteTransportXml
xmlns:ns2="http://esus.ufsc.br/dadoinstalacao" xmlns:ns3="http://esus.ufsc.br/dadotransporte"
xmlns:ns4="http://esus.ufsc.br/cadastroindividual">
<uuidDadoSerializado>2631504-28df1746-28df-28df-28df-28df17466a2e</uuidDadoSerializado>
<tipoDadoSerializado>2</tipoDadoSerializado>
<codIbge>2605004</codIbge>
<cnesDadoSerializado>2631504</cnesDadoSerializado>
<ineDadoSerializado>0000141119</ineDadoSerializado>
<numLote>3</numLote>
<ns4:cadastroIndividualTransport>
    <emSituacaoDeRua>
        <statusSituacaoRua>false</statusSituacaoRua>
    </emSituacaoDeRua>
    <fichaAtualizada>true</fichaAtualizada>
    <identificacaoUsuarioCidadao>
        <codigoIbgeMunicipioNascimento>2611606</codigoIbgeMunicipioNascimento>
        <dataNascimentoCidadao>416923200</dataNascimentoCidadao>
        <desconheceNomeMae>false</desconheceNomeMae>
        <nomeMaeCidadao>EDNA NUNES</nomeMaeCidadao>
        <nacionalidadeCidadao>1</nacionalidadeCidadao>
        <nomeCidadao>ITALO RODRIGO DA SILVA PEREIRA</nomeCidadao>
        <paisNascimento>31</paisNascimento>
        <racaCorCidadao>4</racaCorCidadao>
        <sexoCidadao>0</sexoCidadao>
        <desconheceNomePai>false</desconheceNomePai>
        <microArea>02</microArea>
        <stForaArea>false</stForaArea>
    </identificacaoUsuarioCidadao>
    <informacoesSocioDemograficas>
        <grauInstrucaoCidadao>13</grauInstrucaoCidadao>
        <ocupacaoCodigoCbo2002></ocupacaoCodigoCbo2002>
    </informacoesSocioDemograficas>
    <saidaCidadaoCadastro />
    <statusTermoRecusaCadastroIndividualAtencaoBasica>false</statusTermoRecusaCadastroIndividualAtencaoBasica>
    <tpCdsOrigem>1</tpCdsOrigem>
    <uuid>5444428-d98d44f6-da82-4d75-a08f-d5f69a826e13</uuid>
    <uuidFichaOriginadora>5444428-d98d44f6-da82-4d75-a08f-d5f69a826e13</uuidFichaOriginadora>
    <headerTransport>
        <profissionalCNS>705004017585855</profissionalCNS>
        <cboCodigo_2002>322205</cboCodigo_2002>
        <cnes>5444428</cnes>
        <ine>7023672534</ine>
        <dataAtendimento>1476457200000</dataAtendimento>
        <codigoIbgeMunicipio>2605004</codigoIbgeMunicipio>
    </headerTransport>
</ns4:cadastroIndividualTransport>
<ns2:remetente>
    <contraChave>TREINAMENTO</contraChave>
    <uuidInstalacao>TREINAMENTO</uuidInstalacao>
    <cpfOuCnpj>01234567890</cpfOuCnpj>
    <nomeOuRazaoSocial>ADMINISTRADOR DA INSTALAÇÃO</nomeOuRazaoSocial>
    <versaoSistema>2.1.05</versaoSistema>
    <nomeBancoDados>Postgres</nomeBancoDados>
</ns2:remetente>
<ns2:originadora>
    <contraChave>TREINAMENTO</contraChave>
    <uuidInstalacao>TREINAMENTO</uuidInstalacao>
    <cpfOuCnpj>01234567890</cpfOuCnpj>
    <nomeOuRazaoSocial>ADMINISTRADOR DA INSTALAÇÃO</nomeOuRazaoSocial>
    <versaoSistema>2.1.05</versaoSistema>
    <nomeBancoDados>Postgres</nomeBancoDados>
</ns2:originadora>
<versao major="2" minor="2" revision="0" />
```

and receive error

> XML incompatível com o XSD - cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found
>   starting with element 'nacionalidadeCidadao'. One of '{cnsCidadao,
>   cnsResponsavelFamiliar, telefoneCelular, numeroNisPisPasep, paisNascimento,
>   racaCorCidadao, sexoCidadao, statusEhResponsavel, etnia, nomePaiCidadao,
>   desconheceNomePai, dtNaturalizacao, portariaNaturalizacao, dtEntradaBrasil, microArea,
>   stForaArea}' is expected.

Comment: Looks like you need to check the order of the children in `identificacaoUsuarioCidadao`.

Comment: @DanielHaley how do I see the correct order?

Comment: The error message shows what elements and what order is expected. It doesn't look close to what you have though so maybe you need to check the schema being used to validate.